# Random Prisoner's Trilemma - Python 3 KOTH

Tags: king-of-the-hill, python

The Prisoner's Dilemma, but with 3 choices, and the payoffs are random!

Each round, your bot recieves a 3x3 grid and chooses a row to play.  The grid might be this:

```
4  5  7
3  1  9
9  9  0
```

Each number in the grid is between 0 and 10 (inclusive).  Your score for the round is `grid[your_play][their_play]`, and your opponent's is `grid[their_play][your_play]`.
You play 100(+/-10) rounds in sequence, keeping any information you wish.  The winner is the bot with a higher score at the end (draws are 0.5 wins for both bots).

### Example

Using the grid above:

Player 1: row 2

Player 2: row 2

Both players get 0 points.

---

Player 1: row 1

Player 2: row 0

Player 1 gets 3 points, Player 2 gets 5 points.

## Winning

Each bot will play 10 games of ~100 rounds against each bot (including itself!). Your bot can win in two categories:

- **Score:** the total scores will be summed and the bot with the most points at the end will win.
- **Wins:** a 'win' is counted for the bot with the highest score after the ~100 rounds have been played.

The overall winner will be determined by combining the two tables.  A winner will be accepted about 1 week after the most recent entry, but I will probably continue to update the highscore table if new entries are added.

## Technical details

Write two functions in Python 3 with these signatures:

```py
def strategize(grid: list[list[int]], store: object) -> int
```

```py
def interpret(grid: list[list[int]], moves: tuple(int, int), store: dict) -> None
```

- `strategize` is called each round and should return `0`, `1`, or `2`.

  - `grid` is the 3x3 grid of possible payouts.
  - `store` is an empty dict to store any kind of information you'd like to.
- `interpret` is called after every round.

  - `moves` is a tuple containing (`your_move`, `opponents_move`)

Put your code in the first code block in your answer so the controller can easily pull in your bot.

### Example bots

'Naiive' chooses the row with the highest average payout.

```py
def strategize(grid, store):
    sums = [(sum(x), i) for (i, x) in enumerate(grid)]
    return max(sums)[1]

def interpret(grid, moves, store):
    pass
```

'Random' picks a random row.

```py
import random

def strategize(grid, store):
    return random.randint(0, 2)

def interpret(grid, moves, store):
    pass
```

## Rules

- No cheating by interfering directly with your opponent (through global variables etc.).
- Your function should be relatively quick to execute - the quicker it is, the better.
- You *may* submit multiple entries.

## Controller, arena

**The controller is available at https://github.com/Nucaranlaeg/KOTH-random-prisoner.**

This controller is largely adapted from https://github.com/jthistle/KOTH-counting.

A couple of example bots are provided along with it to demonstrate how to use it.

`arena.py` is what I'll be using to calculate final scores. It pits each bot against each other bot.

`update.py` will fetch all submitted bots from the contest page.

Using the flag `--c` or `-constant` will cause games to be played without randomizing the grid between rounds, purely for interest's sake.

## Current Results

```
By score:
1: Blendo with 12237.8 points
2: The Student with 11791.8 points
3: Naiive with 11728.2 points
4: Analyst with 11591.9 points
5: Min-Maxer with 11155.3 points
6: Rafaam with 11041.1 points
7: Naive Variation with 10963.1 points
8: Villain with 10853.6 points
9: Gradient-Mehscent with 10809.8 points
10: Gentleman with 10715.1 points
11: WhatDoYouExpect with 10676.6 points
12: Thief with 9687.6 points
13: Minimum Maximizer with 9656.0 points
14: HermitCrab with 9654.5 points
15: crab with 9001.9 points
16: Investigator with 8698.0 points
17: Random with 8653.3 points

By wins:
1: The Student with 15.2/16 wins
2: Blendo with 14.8/16 wins
3: Rafaam with 14.1/16 wins
4: WhatDoYouExpect with 13.9/16 wins
5: Naiive with 11.3/16 wins
6: Analyst with 10.8/16 wins
7: Min-Maxer with 10.4/16 wins
8: Naive Variation with 8.1/16 wins
9: Villain with 8.1/16 wins
10: HermitCrab with 7.3/16 wins
11: crab with 6.4/16 wins
12: Thief with 5.1/16 wins
13: Minimum Maximizer with 3.9/16 wins
14: Gradient-Mehscent with 1.9/16 wins
15: Investigator with 1.6/16 wins
16: Random with 1.5/16 wins
17: Gentleman with 1.5/16 wins

Combined leaderboard (fewer pts = better):
1: Blendo  (3 pts)
1: The Student  (3 pts)
3: Naiive  (8 pts)
4: Rafaam  (9 pts)
5: Analyst  (10 pts)
6: Min-Maxer  (12 pts)
7: Naive Variation  (15 pts)
7: WhatDoYouExpect  (15 pts)
9: Villain  (17 pts)
10: Gradient-Mehscent  (23 pts)
11: Thief  (24 pts)
11: HermitCrab  (24 pts)
13: Minimum Maximizer  (26 pts)
13: crab  (26 pts)
15: Gentleman  (27 pts)
16: Investigator  (31 pts)
17: Random  (33 pts)
```

Comment: I think `store` is a totally unnecessary

Comment: @Wasif Why?  The controller doesn't tell you when a new game has started, so if you have a bunch of globals they're going to keep state between games.  Which I don't explicitly stop - you can do it - but you won't know when your opponent changes.  You need some way of keeping track of your opponents' previous moves and the controller doesn't do it for you.  Maybe it should, but that's a separate question.

Comment: oh ok i know how store is neccessary now

Comment: @Spitemaster how would you feel about allowing useres to import `numpy` in their answers (i.e. making `numpy` available in the package list)?

Comment: I never noticed the di in dilemma meant two :)

Comment: Quick Question: could we use a global variable in our bots and have our bots edit the global var that is unique to themselves to make a form of communication, so the bots can be friendly to themselves? If not, then could you make a communication int that values can be read from and pushed to in the interpret stage?

Comment: (Continued) Perhaps have interpret be in the form `def interpret(store, moves, grid, comm)` with comm being an int. I'm also now realizing this question wasn't very quick.

Comment: @Spitemaster and one more thing, can you add some of the new bots into the contest and run it with the new bots?

Comment: @ntjess Importing numpy should be fine.

Comment: @4D4850 You can certainly attempt to communicate using `store`.  But honestly, if I added that, there'd be no point to having the bots play themselves (because there's only one optimal strategy against yourself).

Comment: So much for being a naïve example bot... it's fourth on wins and second overall and on score!

Comment: @Neil I mean, it is the naïve strategy - it just seems that the naïve strategy is a good one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Blendo

Performs approximate bayesian inference over mixtures of different opponent strategies, and optimizes the chosen move with respect to the resulting prediction. Optimizes for expected score when ahead, and score difference when behind or almost equal. Also implements self-recognition. Requires NumPy.

```python
import random
import numpy as np

def nash(grid):
    payoffs = regrets = zeros = np.zeros(3)
    strategy = np.full((3,), 1. / 3)
    for _ in range(10):
        payoffs = np.dot(grid, strategy)
        v = np.dot(strategy, payoffs)
        regrets = np.maximum(regrets + payoffs - v, zeros) + 1e-9
        strategy = regrets / regrets.sum()
    return strategy

def max_strategy(f):
    def get_strategy(grid):
        values = f(grid)
        strategy = values == np.max(values)
        return strategy / np.sum(strategy)
    return get_strategy

expected = max_strategy(lambda grid: np.sum(grid, axis=1))
maximin = max_strategy(lambda grid: np.min(grid, axis=1))
maxidiag = max_strategy(np.diag)

def strategize(grid, store):
    if not store:
        store['is_me'] = True
        store['side'] = 0
        store['means'] = np.array([0.73336847, -0.38686278, -0.48677562, 0.09995684, -0.06624643, 0.38667801, -0.55640674, -0.1005102])
        store['stds'] = np.array([1.6364209, 0.9467514, 0.79119316, 1.54119291, 1.44484517, 1.73075995, 0.8261992, 0.7124938])
        store['score_delta'] = 0
    grid = np.array(grid)
    delta_grid = grid - grid.T
    predictions = np.array([np.full(3, 1./3), nash(grid), nash(delta_grid), expected(grid), expected(delta_grid), maximin(grid), maximin(delta_grid), maxidiag(grid)]).T
    weights = np.exp(np.random.normal(store['means'], store['stds']))
    weights /= np.sum(weights)
    probabilities = np.dot(predictions, weights)
    store['predictions'] = predictions
    if store['is_me']:
        l, r = max(((i, j) for i in range(3) for j in range(i + 1)), key=lambda t: grid[t[0]][t[1]] + grid[t[1]][t[0]])
        store['sides'] = (l, r)
        if store['side'] == -1:
            return l
        if store['side'] == 1:
            return r
        return random.choice((l, r))
    if store['score_delta'] <= 5:
        grid = delta_grid
    else:
        grid = grid - 1e-9 * grid.T
    return int(np.argmax(np.dot(grid, probabilities)))

def interpret(grid, moves, store):
    predictions = store['predictions'][moves[1]]
    store['score_delta'] += grid[moves[0]][moves[1]] - grid[moves[1]][moves[0]]
    params = np.random.normal(store['means'], store['stds'], (200, 8))
    weights = np.exp(params)
    weights = weights / weights.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
    likelihood = np.dot(weights, predictions)
    c = 1. / np.mean(likelihood)
    store['means'] = c * (likelihood[:,None] * params).mean(axis=0)
    store['stds'] = np.sqrt(c * (likelihood[:,None] * (params - store['means'][None,:]) ** 2).mean(axis=0))
    if store['is_me']:
        l, r = store['sides']
        if moves[1] not in (l, r):
            store['is_me'] = False
        else:
            if store['side'] == 0:
                if l != r and moves[0] != moves[1]:
                    if moves[0] == l:
                        store['side'] = -1
                    else:
                        store['side'] = 1
            else:
                if store['side'] == -1 and moves[1] != r:
                    store['is_me'] = False
                elif store['side'] == 1 and moves[1] != l:
                    store['is_me'] = False
```

## <s>Switcheroo</s> No longer Competing

Switches between a few different strategies based on expected performance. Also implements self-recognition to maximally cooperate with itself.

```python
import random

def sample(distribution):
    u = random.random()
    for i, p in enumerate(distribution):
        u -= p
        if u <= 0:
            break
    return i

def nash(grid):
    grid = [[grid[i][j] for j in range(3)] for i in range(3)]
    payoffs = [0] * 3
    regrets = [0] * 3
    strategy = [1. / 3] * 3
    for i in range(10):
        for a in range(3):
            payoffs[a] = sum(p * v for p, v in zip(strategy, grid[a]))
        v = sum(p * v for p, v in zip(strategy, payoffs))
        regrets = [max(r + q - v, 0) for r, q in zip(regrets, payoffs)]
        total_regret = sum(regrets)
        if total_regret == 0:
            strategy = [1. / 3] * 3
        else:
            c = 1. / total_regret
            strategy = [r * c for r in regrets]
    return strategy

def expected(grid):
    values = [(sum(row), -sum(col)) for row, col in zip(grid, zip(*grid))]
    v_max = max(values)
    strategy = [int(v == v_max) for v in values]
    c = 1. / sum(strategy)
    return [p * c for p in strategy]

def strategize(grid, store):
    if not store:
        store['outcomes'] = [[1. / 11 for _ in range(11)] for _ in range(2)]
        store['round_number'] = 0
        store['is_me'] = True
        store['side'] = 0
    scores = [max(sum(i * n for i, n in enumerate(a)) / sum(a) for a in (a0, [random.gammavariate(n, 1) for n in a0])) for a0 in store['outcomes']]
    strategy = scores.index(max(scores))
    nash_strategy = nash(grid)
    expected_strategy = expected(grid)
    store['strategies'] = [nash_strategy, expected_strategy]
    if store['is_me']:
        l, r = max(((i, j) for i in range(3) for j in range(i + 1)), key=lambda t: grid[t[0]][t[1]] + grid[t[1]][t[0]])
        store['sides'] = (l, r)
        if store['side'] == -1:
            return l
        if store['side'] == 1:
            return r
        return random.choice((l, r))
    return sample(store['strategies'][strategy])

def interpret(grid, moves, store):
    for i, s in enumerate(store['strategies']):
        for a, p in enumerate(s):
            v = grid[a][moves[1]]
            store['outcomes'][i][v] += p
    if store['is_me']:
        l, r = store['sides']
        if moves[1] not in (l, r):
            store['is_me'] = False
        else:
            if store['side'] == 0:
                if l != r and moves[0] != moves[1]:
                    if moves[0] == l:
                        store['side'] = -1
                    else:
                        store['side'] = 1
            else:
                if store['side'] == -1 and moves[1] != r:
                    store['is_me'] = False
                elif store['side'] == 1 and moves[1] != l:
                    store['is_me'] = False
    store['round_number'] += 1
```

Comment: Do you need the if False and if True?

Comment: @ophact Fixed. They were left over from a previous experiment.

Comment: I implemented self-recognition since I thought it was clever. However, not understanding how your bot does it, I reimplemented it from scratch for my bot.

Comment: How does your bot implement self recognition?

Comment: @4D4850 In each turn I identify an (i, j) pair which maximizes total utility, and then each bot randomly picks i or j until i != j and one picks min(i, j) and the other picks max(i, j), at which point they will continue to do so for the rest of the game.

Answer (score 5):

## crab

crab wants everyone to die. crab is happy when everyone else is unhappy. Yes, crab is back.

```python
def strategize(grid, store):
    aa = grid[0][0] #aa means '0-0'.
    ab = grid[1][0] #and similarly for the others.
    ac = grid[2][0]
    ba = grid[0][1]
    bb = grid[1][1] #I wish I had a macro to do this.
    bc = grid[2][1]
    ca = grid[0][2]
    cb = grid[1][2]
    cc = grid[2][2]
    a = (aa * ab * ac)/3 # a, b, and c are the respective averages.
    b = (ba * bb * bc)/3
    c = (ca * cb * cc)/3
    if a <= min(b, c):
        return 0
    if b <= min(a, c):
        return 1
    return 2

def interpret(grid, moves, store):
    pass
```

Specifically, it picks the value that hurts the opponent the most.

Answer (score 4):

## Analyst

```py
def strategize(grid, store = None):
    nonzero = [a for a in range(3)]
    if len([a for a in grid if not 0 in a]):
        maximum = max(nonzero, key=lambda index: sum(grid[index]) if not 0 in grid[index] else 0)
        if max(grid[maximum]) > 5:
            return maximum
        else:
            return max(nonzero, key=lambda arr: max(grid[arr]))
    return __import__('random').randint(0, 2)
def interpret(grid, moves, store):
    pass
```

[Try it online with sample test cases](https://tio.run/##dVFdbsIwDH7nFH6jkaKpo0MDJHaEXaCqqkw1LIIklRsm4PKdnYWfSZCXOPb3p7g/xe/gq0VP49jhBoZIJuLWnrHYku00NwIhrOEzeFSrCfDxwZ@RAjdrA5tAYMB6IOO3WFSqSRi7gT364h4getL3IUIpDdNkQTnOHK07OBblqsgWGnZ4Wu@N@@pEosPjCoaDS9Hq9G7UP8m7AeB@QCjV1YFxIp0g2Y3ZHzC/hZBDGA/kL3muI1F7BnwY1xCtbob8atRflsxrW@v6QLFtiyn/XRfcVL1IYX0sSg0zNZGF8AupZ07ehws/OOS15O/rzTCMPQnvbn11/aZhruG90VBXGl41LKVc8q2hbCTOA9JlzEhmzDRUuUz8JySeSWJB8r3IprPkn5zGXw)

Analyst is a bot that tries to find the highest average out of nonzero possibilities, if the maximum is not high enough, then look for the index with the highest maximum. If all sublists have zeroes, choose randomly.

Answer (score 4):

## WhatDoYouExpect

```python
def strategize(grid, store):
    expected = [0] * 3
    for my_play in range(3):
        for opponent_play in range(3):
            expected[my_play] += grid[my_play][opponent_play] - grid[opponent_play][my_play]
    return expected.index(max(expected))

def interpret(grid, moves, store):
    pass
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZBNCoNADIX3niLLsX8U3JSCJxEpQyfagZoJmbFoLz9Vq1I3zfLLy0teuA8PR9mFJUaDFfggOmBt36hqseYwACeYXhMYCjvGe0ADORTnEnaQTbhyAk1/46fuwRKIphpVNs8sAsfsCCn8kf2uKGbDEvY5jJesoNg4lXD8trd0VU/mgqEVWr1Plgx2qtGdWlCaJskY31JA4UE/p2/cC/32Cay9j/ED)

Always plays the move with the maximum expected value.

Comment: The TIO link is nonfunctional, and doesn't print to output. Also, this seems a bit similar to naiive and to part of my newest bot, which is kinda cool.

Comment: @4D4850 I used TIO because it's convenient and used for most everything else on this site, obviously the code is run elsewhere. I posted before those answers so any similarity is on them.

Comment: Yes, I know. It's just kinda cool that we had similar ideas. It is a pretty good strategy in terms of wins, though. Hopefully crab doesn't break it.

Comment: @4D4850 Yeah, when I first looked at the puzzle and was going over moves I would play, I wanted to calculate the max expected value as my move.

Comment: I made my third bot because I realized that it was important to balance ruining your enemy and doing well.

Answer (score 4):

## Investigator

Plays naive and tit-for-tat for a few rounds, then investigates opponent responses every few rounds to find any adversarial responsive strategies. Following this, it assembles the best countermoves into a graph and executes the most positive cycle. Should be good versus both naive non-responsive opponents and basic responsive adversaries.

**EDIT: In retrospect, the original problem randomizes the scoring grid after each round, which breaks this solution. This would likely do well if the scoring grid isn't randomized though.**

```python
def naive(grid):
    return max((sum(grid[move][opp]-grid[opp][move] for opp in range(3)), move) for move in range(3))[1]

def strategize(grid, store):
    if not store:
        store["round"] = 0
        store["responses"] = []
        store["sequence"] = None
    if store["round"] == 0:
        return naive(grid)
    elif store["round"] < 6:
        return store["responses"][-1][1]
    else:
        return store["sequence"][store["round"]%len(store["sequence"])]

def most_common(lst):
    return max(set(lst), key=lst.count)

def recursive_evaluate(start, trail, opponent, response, depth):
    if depth == 6:
        return trail
    trail[0].append(opponent[trail[1][-1]] if len(trail[1]) > 0 else opponent[start])
    trail[1].append(response[trail[1][-1]] if len(trail[1]) > 0 else start)
    return recursive_evaluate(start, trail, opponent, response, depth+1)

def interpret(grid, moves, store):
    store["responses"].append(moves)
    if store["round"] % 6 == 6-1:
        filtered = [[store["responses"][i+1][1] for i in range(store["round"]) if store["responses"][i][0] == me] for me in range(3)]
        default = naive(grid)
        opponent = [most_common(filtered[me]) if len(filtered[me])>0 else default for me in range(3)]
        response = [max((grid[move][opponent[me]]-grid[opponent[me]][move], move) for move in range(3))[1] for me in range(3)]
        evaluate = [recursive_evaluate(start, [[], []], opponent, response, 0) for start in range(3)]
        scoring = [(sum(grid[evaluate[start][1][i]][evaluate[start][0][i]] for i in range(len(evaluate[start][1])))-sum(grid[evaluate[start][0][i]][evaluate[start][1][i]] for i in range(len(evaluate[start][1]))), evaluate[start][1]) for start in range(3)]
        store["sequence"] = max(scoring)[1]
    store["round"] += 1
```

Comment: @Spitemaster, do you think you could, for interest's sake, add a second mode where scoring grids are kept constant for each run of +-100 games? I feel like it might make things interesting :)

Comment: Yep, I can stick that in the controller.  It'll be something like `-constant`; I'll document it.

Comment: Nope, sorry, looks like it's almost exactly the same if the grids are the same round to round.

Answer (score 3):

## Min-Maxer

```python
def strategize(grid, store):
    max_best_moves = []
    max_best_move_score = float("-inf")

    for my_move in range(3):
        worst_score = min(grid[my_move])
        if worst_score == max_best_move_score: max_best_moves.append(my_move)
        elif worst_score > max_best_move_score:
            max_best_move_score = worst_score
            max_best_moves = [my_move]

    min_best_moves = []
    min_best_move_score = float("inf")

    for my_move in range(3):
        opp_best_score = max(grid[opp_move][my_move] for opp_move in range(3))
        if opp_best_score == min_best_move_score: min_best_moves.append(my_move)
        elif opp_best_score < min_best_move_score:
            min_best_move_score = opp_best_score
            min_best_moves = [my_move]

    best_of_both = [move for move in max_best_moves if move in min_best_moves]
    if best_of_both: return best_of_both[0]
    return max_best_moves[0]

def interpret(grid, moves, store): pass
```

Checks for moves that both maximize the worst case for itself and minimize the best case for its opponent. If there aren't any that are both at once, then it prefers moves that give itself points over sabotaging the opponent.

Comment: I just realized my newest bot is similar to yours, but mine is way less efficient. Probably.

Comment: Now my bot implements self-recognition.

Answer (score 2):

## Thief

This person is a master pickpocket of credit cards that have expired.

```python
def strategize(grid, store):
    if not store:
        store['opmove'] = 3
    if store['opmove'] == 3:
      sums = [(sum(x), i) for (i, x) in enumerate(grid)]
      return max(sums)[1]
    elif grid[store['mymove']][store['opmove']] > grid[store['opmove']][store['mymove']]:
      sums = [(sum(x), i) for (i, x) in enumerate(grid)]
      return max(sums)[1]
    else:
      return store['opmove']

def interpret(grid, moves, store):
    store['opmove'] = moves[1]
    store['mymove'] = moves[0]
```

The idea is that if it's the first round, it'll act like naiive, if it won the last round, it'll act like naiive, but if it lost the last round, it'll unconditionally return the opponents move. It isn't very smart. Please provide recommendations and bug fixes.

v1.0

- Initial write

v1.1

- Rewrote some to use store rather than plain global variables.

Answer (score 2):

## Naive Variation

Naive works well, try to fight against aggressive players by choosing rows where every value has a reasonable payout (i.e. where several means are comparable, prefer rows with lower standard deviation)

```python
def std_dev(numbers):
    wgt = 1 / len(numbers)
    mean = sum(numbers) * wgt
    sqdiff_wgt = wgt * sum((number - mean) ** 2 for number in numbers)
    return sqdiff_wgt ** 0.5

def strategize(grid, store=None):
    bestScore = 0
    bestIdx = -1
    for ii, row in enumerate(grid):
        rowSum = sum(row)
        # Avoid numeric inflation
        std = max(std_dev(row), 1)
        score = rowSum/std
        if score > bestScore:
            bestScore = score
            bestIdx = ii

    return bestIdx


def interpret(grid, moves, store):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

## Gentleman

This one is kind, and assumes everyone else is too. Optimizes for the opponent being Gentleman and picks the highest scoring option along the diagonal.

```python
def strategize(grid, store = None):
    nums = [0,1,2]
    winner = 0
    score = -1
    for i in nums:
        if grid[i][i] > score:
            winner = i
            score = grid[i][i]
    return winner

def interpret(grid, moves, store):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

## Gradient-Mehscent

It uses a terrible method of maximizing the score.

```python
weightA = 1
weightB = 1

def strategize(grid, store):
    global weightA, weightB
    aa = grid[0][0] #aa means '0-0'.
    ab = grid[1][0] #and similarly for the others.
    ac = grid[2][0]
    ba = grid[0][1]
    bb = grid[1][1] #I wish I had a macro to do this.
    bc = grid[2][1]
    ca = grid[0][2]
    cb = grid[1][2]
    cc = grid[2][2]

    dd = grid[0][0] 
    de = grid[0][1] 
    df = grid[0][2]
    ed = grid[1][0]
    ee = grid[1][1] #autocorrect is annoying
    ef = grid[1][2]
    fd = grid[2][0]
    fe = grid[2][1]
    ff = grid[2][2]

    a = (aa + ab + ac)/3 # a, b, c, d, e, and f are the respective averages.
    b = (ba + bb + bc)/3
    c = (ca + cb + cc)/3
    d = (dd + de + df)/3
    e = (ed + ee + ef)/3
    f = (fd + fe + ff)/3
    scoreOfZero = (weightA * a + weightB * d)/2
    scoreOfOne = (weightA * b + weightB * e)/2
    scoreOfTwo = (weightA * c + weightB * f)/2
    if scoreOfZero >= max(scoreOfOne, scoreOfTwo):
      return 0
    if scoreOfOne >= max(scoreOfZero, scoreOfTwo):
      return 1
    return 2

def interpret(grid, moves, store):
    aa = grid[0][0] #aa means '0-0'.
    ab = grid[1][0] #and similarly for the others.
    ac = grid[2][0]
    ba = grid[0][1]
    bb = grid[1][1] #I wish I had a macro to do this.
    bc = grid[2][1]
    ca = grid[0][2]
    cb = grid[1][2]
    cc = grid[2][2]

    dd = grid[0][0] 
    de = grid[0][1] 
    df = grid[0][2]
    ed = grid[1][0]
    ee = grid[1][1] #autocorrect is annoying
    ef = grid[1][2]
    fd = grid[2][0]
    fe = grid[2][1]
    ff = grid[2][2]

    a = (aa + ab + ac)/3 # a, b, c, d, e, and f are the respective averages.
    b = (ba + bb + bc)/3
    c = (ca + cb + cc)/3
    d = (dd + de + df)/3
    e = (ed + ee + ef)/3
    f = (fd + fe + ff)/3
    global weightA, weightB
    simWeightA = weightA + 0.01
    simWeightB = weightB + 0.01
    simScoreOfZero = (simWeightA * a + simWeightB * d)/2
    simScoreOfOne = (simWeightA * b + simWeightB * e)/2
    simScoreOfTwo = (simWeightA * c + simWeightB * f)/2
    if simScoreOfZero >= max(simScoreOfOne, simScoreOfTwo):
      upupscore = grid[0][moves[1]]
    elif simScoreOfOne >= max(simScoreOfZero, simScoreOfTwo):
      upupscore = grid[1][moves[1]]
    else:
      upupscore = grid[2][moves[1]]
    
    simWeightA = weightA + 0.01
    simWeightB = weightB - 0.01
    simScoreOfZero = (simWeightA * a + simWeightB * d)/2
    simScoreOfOne = (simWeightA * b + simWeightB * e)/2
    simScoreOfTwo = (simWeightA * c + simWeightB * f)/2
    if simScoreOfZero >= max(simScoreOfOne, simScoreOfTwo):
      updownscore = grid[0][moves[1]]
    elif simScoreOfOne >= max(simScoreOfZero, simScoreOfTwo):
      updownscore = grid[1][moves[1]]
    else:
      updownscore = grid[2][moves[1]]
    simWeightA = weightA - 0.01
    simWeightB = weightB + 0.01
    simScoreOfZero = (simWeightA * a + simWeightB * d)/2
    simScoreOfOne = (simWeightA * b + simWeightB * e)/2
    simScoreOfTwo = (simWeightA * c + simWeightB * f)/2
    if simScoreOfZero >= max(simScoreOfOne, simScoreOfTwo):
      downupscore = grid[0][moves[1]]
    elif simScoreOfOne >= max(simScoreOfZero, simScoreOfTwo):
      downupscore = grid[1][moves[1]]
    else:
      downupscore = grid[2][moves[1]]
    simWeightA = weightA - 0.01
    simWeightB = weightB - 0.01
    simScoreOfZero = (simWeightA * a + simWeightB * d)/2
    simScoreOfOne = (simWeightA * b + simWeightB * e)/2
    simScoreOfTwo = (simWeightA * c + simWeightB * f)/2
    if simScoreOfZero >= max(simScoreOfOne, simScoreOfTwo):
      downdownscore = grid[0][moves[1]]
    elif simScoreOfOne >= max(simScoreOfZero, simScoreOfTwo):
      downdownscore = grid[1][moves[1]]
    else:
      downdownscore = grid[2][moves[1]]
    if upupscore >= max(updownscore, downupscore, downdownscore):
      weightA = weightA + 0.01
      weightB = weightB + 0.01
    elif updownscore >= max(upupscore, downupscore, downdownscore):
      weightA = weightA + 0.01
      weightB = weightB - 0.01
    elif downupscore >= max(upupscore, updownscore, downdownscore):
      weightA = weightA - 0.01
      weightB = weightB + 0.01
    else:
      weightA = weightA - 0.01
      weightB = weightB - 0.01
```

### How It Works

It probably doesn't. However, it should slowly move `weightA` and `weightB` so the bot is more effective. It's basically a tiny AI. The real core of Mehscent is the giant interpret function, which just plays around with the weights until something good happens.

Comment: You have `else` in a bunch of places you should have `else:`

Comment: Fixed. It seems a little weird for `else` to need a colon.

Comment: You need to use `store["weightA"]` instead of `weightA` - they're not otherwise stored.

Comment: @Spitemaster I thought that global variables could be used, although they wouldn't be cleared between rounds, and I don't want the weights to be cleared between rounds. That was my logic behind using a global variable.

Comment: Yeah, you could do that.  But then you need to declare them globally and have `global weightA` at the start of your functions.

Comment: Fixed. Now `global weightA` is at the start of the strategize function.

Comment: You've also got a problem with `a`, `b`, etc. not being defined in `interpret`.

Comment: Fixed yet again, this time with a copy-paste because the values shouldn't be changing between execution of strategize and execution of interpret.

Comment: This is one of the more interesting ones IMO. Doesn't perform well, but unique compared to the others (like mine)

Comment: Yeah. I couldn't figure out how to implement proper gradient ascent, so I just made this instead.

Answer (score 1):

## HermitCrab

Very akin to a normal crab, but never picks an option that leaves itself out in the dust if it can help it.

```python
def strategize(grid, store = None):
    nums = [0,1,2]
    winner = 0
    opponentScores = [-1, -1, -1]
    for i in nums:
        opponentScores[i] = (grid[0][i]*grid[1][i]*grid[2][i])+(.1*(grid[0][i]+grid[1][i]+grid[2][i]))
    fear = [0]
    fearful = 10
    terror = 0
    for i in nums:
        if min(grid[i]) < fearful:
            fear = [i]
            fearful = min(grid[i])
            terror = 0
        elif min(grid[i]) == fearful:
            terror = terror + 1
            fear.append(min(grid[i]))
    mini = 100
    if terror == 2:
        fear = []
    for i in nums:
        if i not in fear:
            if opponentScores[i] < mini:
                winner = i
                mini = opponentScores[i]
    return winner

def interpret(grid, moves, store):
    pass
```

Comment: Python doesn't have `++`.

Comment: @Spitemaster Weird, my IDE has it work for me. I'll edit.

Comment: Neat!  What IDE do you use? (You can use `+= 1`)

Comment: When I'm just throwing something together (like here) I use pyzo

Answer (score 1):

## Minimum Maximizer

Not to be confused with the other one

```python
def strategize(grid, store):
    a = min(grid[0])
    b = min(grid[1])
    c = min(grid[2])
    if a >= min(b, c):
      return 0
    if b >= min(a, c):
      return 1
    return 2
def interpret(grid, moves, store):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

## Rafaam

My final entry, came to me last night. Named after my favorite duplicitous multiverse-traveling villain, this optimizes its own success *compared* to its opponent, but sometimes acts kindly, and in doing so, determines if it's facing against itself, possibly changing from cruel to kind.

```python
def strategize(grid, store = None):
    if not store:
        store["round"] = 0
        store["opponent"] = 0
    nums = [0,1,2]
    kind = False
    if store["opponent"] == 1:
        kind = True
    elif store["opponent"] == 0 and store["round"] == 2:
        kind = True
    if kind:
        winner = 0
        score = -1
        for i in nums:
            if grid[i][i] > score:
                winner = i
                score = grid[i][i]
        return winner
    scores = []
    for i in nums:
        row = []
        for j in nums:
            row.append((grid[i][j],(grid[i][j]/(grid[j][i]+0.01))))
        scores.append(row)
    safeRows = []
    ratios = [[col[1] for col in row] for row in scores]
    for i in nums:
        non = ratios[i][:i] + ratios[i][(i + 1):]
        if min(non) > 0.95:
            safeRows.append(i)
    
    scores = []
    for i in nums:
        scores.append((ratios[i][0]+ratios[i][1]+ratios[i][2]-ratios[i][i],i))
    sortedScores = sorted(scores, key=lambda tup:(-tup[0],tup[1]))
    for i in sortedScores:
        if i[1] in safeRows:
            return i[1]
    return sortedScores[0][1]

def interpret(grid, moves, store):
    if moves[0] != moves[1]:
        store["opponent"] = -1
    elif store["round"] == 4 and store["opponent"] == 0:
        store["opponent"] = 1
    store["round"] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## Why_do_I_have_so_many_ideas?!?!

It works. It's trash, but it works on Debian Buster with python 3.7.3

```python
isFriendlyOne = 0
isFriendlyTwo = 0
def strategize(grid, store):
    global isFriendlyOne, isFriendlyTwo
    aa = grid[0][0] #aa means '0-0'.
    ab = grid[1][0] #and similarly for the others.
    ac = grid[2][0]
    ba = grid[0][1]
    bb = grid[1][1] #I wish I had a macro to do this.
    bc = grid[2][1]
    ca = grid[0][2]
    cb = grid[1][2]
    cc = grid[2][2]

    dd = grid[0][0] 
    de = grid[0][1] 
    df = grid[0][2]
    ed = grid[1][0]
    ee = grid[1][1] #autocorrect is annoying
    ef = grid[1][2]
    fd = grid[2][0]
    fe = grid[2][1]
    ff = grid[2][2]

    a = (aa + ab + ac)/3 # a, b, c, d, e, and f are the respective averages.
    b = (ba + bb + bc)/3
    c = (ca + cb + cc)/3
    d = (dd + de + df)/3
    e = (ed + ee + ef)/3
    f = (fd + fe + ff)/3
    scoreOfZero = (a + d)/2
    scoreOfOne = (b + e)/2
    scoreOfTwo = (c + f)/2
    if isFriendlyOne != 2:
      if scoreOfZero <= min(scoreOfOne, scoreOfTwo):
        return 0
      if scoreOfOne <= min(scoreOfZero, scoreOfTwo):
        return 1
      return 2
    elif isFriendlyTwo != 2:
      if scoreOfZero <= min(scoreOfOne, scoreOfTwo):
        return 0
      if scoreOfOne <= min(scoreOfZero, scoreOfTwo):
        return 1
      return 2
    else:
      if d >= max(e, f):
        if dd >= max(de, df):
          return 0
        if de >= max(dd, df):
          return 1
        return 2
      if e >= max(d, f):
        if ed >= max(ee, ef):
          return 0
        if ee >= max(ed, ef):
          return 1
        return 2
      if fd >= max(fe, ff):
        return 0
      if fe >= max(fd, ff):
        return 1
      return 2

def interpret(grid, moves, store):
    global isFriendlyOne, isFriendlyTwo
    if not store:
      store['wroteOne'] = False
      store['wroteTwo'] = False
      isFriendlyOne = 0
      isFriendlyTwo = 0
    if moves[0] != moves[1]:
      store['oldMatch'] = True
    if max(isFriendlyOne, isFriendlyTwo) < 1:
      if moves[1] == 0:
        if grid[0][moves[0]] >= max(grid[1][moves[0]], grid[2][moves[0]]):
          if moves[0] > 0:
            isFriendlyOne = 1
            store['wroteOne'] = True
      if moves[1] == 1:
        if grid[1][moves[0]] >= max(grid[2][moves[0]], grid[0][moves[0]]):
          if moves[0] > 1:
            isFriendlyOne = 1
            store['wroteOne'] = True
          elif moves[0] < 1:
            isFriendlyTwo = 1
            store['wroteTwo'] = True
      if moves[1] == 2:
        if grid[2][moves[0]] >= max(grid[1][moves[0]], grid[0][moves[0]]):
          if moves[0] > 2:
            isFriendlyOne = 1
            store['wroteOne'] = True
          elif moves[0] < 2:
            isFriendlyTwo = 1
            store['wroteTwo'] = True
    if store['wroteOne']:
      if isFriendlyTwo == 1:
        isFriendlyOne = 2
    if store['wroteTwo']:
      if isFriendlyOne == 1:
        isFriendlyTwo = 2
```

I ***think*** the new version implements self-recognition? Either this bot or Switcheroo has the most lines, although Switcheroo is vastly more complex. The entire interpret function is just for self-recognition.

Comment: You've got a bunch of places where you have an assignment in an if statement, and you're missing a bunch of colons.

Comment: Dumb mistakes hopefully fixed. Somehow I forgot you have to use == for checking if two things are equal.

Comment: You've got a bunch of syntax errors (missing colons, missing closing brackets at the end of the `if grid[2][moves[0]]` lines) and other errors (`if not store["oldMatch"]:` should be `if "oldMatch" not in store:`, if there is an `oldMatch` in `store`, `isFriendlyOne` will not be defined).  Can you please attempt to get this running yourself?

Answer (score 0):

## Villain

My personal approach to solving the problem

```python
def strategize(grid, store = None):
    nums = [0,1,2]
    safe = [(a, True) if 0 not in a else (a, False) for a in grid]
    safeNums = []
    for i in nums:
        if safe[i][1]:
            safeNums.append(i)
    if len(safeNums) == 1:
        return safeNums[0]
    rudeNums = []
    for i in nums:
        rude = False
        for j in grid:
            if j[i] == 0:
                rude = True
        if rude:
            rudeNums.append(i)
    geniusNums = []
    for i in nums:
        if i in safeNums and i in rudeNums:
            geniusNums.append(i)
    if len(geniusNums) == 1:
        return geniusNums[0]
    if len(geniusNums) > 1:
        winner = geniusNums[0]
        mini = -1
        for i in geniusNums:
            newMin = min(grid[i])
            if newMin > mini:
                winner = i
                mini = newMin
        return winner
    if len(safeNums) > 1:
        winner = safeNums[0]
        mini = -1
        for i in safeNums:
            newMin = min(grid[i])
            if newMin > mini:
                winner = i
                mini = newMin
        return winner
    if len(rudeNums) == 1:
        return rudeNums[0]
    if len(rudeNums) >= 1:
        winner = rudeNums[0]
        mini = -1
        for i in rudeNums:
            newMin = grid[i][0]+grid[i][1]+grid[i][2]
            if newMin > mini:
                winner = i
                mini = newMin
        return winner
    score = 0
    winner = 0
    for i in nums:
        newScore = grid[i][0]+grid[i][1]+grid[i][2]
        if newScore > score:
            score = newScore
            winner = i
    return winner

def interpret(grid, moves, store):
    pass
```

Should be a fine algorithm- first prioritizes safety, then screwing over opponents, then personal score. It doesn't bother minimizing opponent score, only giving them the potential for 0s.

Answer (score 0):

## The Student

My late entry to the competition, spawned originally out of a simple desire to beat naiive, which has been remarkably successful.  Eventually it morphed into this monstrosity that attempts to predict opponent moves and tracks likelihood of a some strategies I or people I talked to thought of.

```
import random

def strategize(grid, store):
    possible_round_results = [
        ((0, 0), (grid[0][0], grid[0][0]), 0),
        ((0, 1), (grid[0][1], grid[1][0]), grid[0][1] - grid[1][0]),
        ((0, 2), (grid[0][2], grid[2][0]), grid[0][2] - grid[2][0]),
        ((1, 0), (grid[1][0], grid[0][1]), grid[1][0] - grid[0][1]),
        ((1, 1), (grid[1][1], grid[1][1]), 0),
        ((1, 2), (grid[1][2], grid[2][1]), grid[1][2] - grid[2][1]),
        ((2, 0), (grid[2][0], grid[0][2]), grid[2][0] - grid[0][2]),
        ((2, 1), (grid[2][1], grid[1][2]), grid[2][1] - grid[1][2]),
        ((2, 2), (grid[2][2], grid[2][2]), 0)
    ]

    # Interpret data from Store to try to determine opponent and optimize
    if('facing_self' in store and store['facing_self']):
        # Determine move combination that gives the highest total points
        max_score_result_index = max([(x[1][0] + x[1][1], i) for (i, x) in enumerate(possible_round_results)])[1]
        if(store['should_pick_low'] is None):
            random.seed()
            return possible_round_results[max_score_result_index][0][random.randrange(0,2)]
        elif(store['should_pick_low']):
            return max(possible_round_results[max_score_result_index][0])
        else:
            return min(possible_round_results[max_score_result_index][0])
    opponent_move = -1
    if('opponent_strategy_probabilities' in store):
        opponent_probabilities = [(store['opponent_strategy_probabilities'][x], x) for x in store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']]
        opponent_probabilities.remove((store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['self'], 'self'))
        most_likely_opponent = max(opponent_probabilities)[1]
        if(most_likely_opponent == 'safe_scorer'):
            # safe_scorer
            opponent_move = 0
            safe_moves = []
            for i in range(0,9,3):
                if(min([possible_round_results[i][2], possible_round_results[i+1][2], possible_round_results[i+2][2]]) >= 0):
                    safe_moves.append((possible_round_results[i][2] + possible_round_results[i+1][2] + possible_round_results[i+2][2], possible_round_results[i][0][0]))
            if(len(safe_moves) > 0):
                opponent_move = max(safe_moves)[1]
            else:
                #resort to naiive_score_differential after loosing out on safety
                opponent_move = max([(possible_round_results[i][2] + possible_round_results[i+1][2] + possible_round_results[i+2][2], possible_round_results[i][0][0]) for i in range(0, 9, 3)])[1]
        elif(most_likely_opponent == 'hurtful'):
            # hurtful
            opponent_move = min([(sum(x), i) for (i, x) in enumerate(grid)])[1]
        elif(most_likely_opponent == 'cooperative'):
            # cooperative 
            opponent_move = max([(x[i], i) for (i, x) in enumerate(grid)])[1]
        elif(most_likely_opponent == 'minimize_losses'):
            # minimize_losses
            opponent_move = max([(min(x), i) for (i, x) in enumerate(grid)])[1]
        elif(most_likely_opponent == 'highest_expected_val'):
            # highest_expected_val
            opponent_move = max([(x[2], x[0][1]) for x in possible_round_results])[1]
        elif(most_likely_opponent == 'naiive_score_differential'):
            # naiive_scored_differential
            opponent_move = max([(possible_round_results[i][2] + possible_round_results[i+1][2] + possible_round_results[i+2][2], possible_round_results[i][0][0]) for i in range(0, 9, 3)])[1]
        else:
            # naiive
            opponent_move = max([(sum(x), i) for (i, x) in enumerate(grid)])[1]
    else:
        #assumed naiive
        opponent_move = max([(sum(x), i) for (i, x) in enumerate(grid)])[1]
    score_margin = 10
    if('my_score' in store and store['my_score'] >= store['opponent_score'] + score_margin):
        return max([(x[opponent_move], i) for (i, x) in enumerate(grid)])[1]
    else:
        possible_moves = []
        for result in possible_round_results:
            if(result[0][1] == opponent_move):
                possible_moves.append(result)
        return max([(x[2], i) for (i, x) in enumerate(possible_moves)])[1]

def interpret(grid, moves, store):
    possible_round_results = [
        ((0, 0), (grid[0][0], grid[0][0]), 0),
        ((0, 1), (grid[0][1], grid[1][0]), grid[0][1] - grid[1][0]),
        ((0, 2), (grid[0][2], grid[2][0]), grid[0][2] - grid[2][0]),
        ((1, 0), (grid[1][0], grid[0][1]), grid[1][0] - grid[0][1]),
        ((1, 1), (grid[1][1], grid[1][1]), 0),
        ((1, 2), (grid[1][2], grid[2][1]), grid[1][2] - grid[2][1]),
        ((2, 0), (grid[2][0], grid[0][2]), grid[2][0] - grid[0][2]),
        ((2, 1), (grid[2][1], grid[1][2]), grid[2][1] - grid[1][2]),
        ((2, 2), (grid[2][2], grid[2][2]), 0)
    ]

    # Estimate probability that opponent is using a specific strategy
    naiive_move = max([(sum(x), i) for (i, x) in enumerate(grid)])[1]
    naiive_score_differnetial_move = max([(possible_round_results[i][2] + possible_round_results[i+1][2] + possible_round_results[i+2][2], possible_round_results[i][0][0]) for i in range(0, 9, 3)])[1]
    cooperative_move = max([(x[i], i) for (i, x) in enumerate(grid)])[1]
    minimize_losses_move = max([(min(x), i) for (i, x) in enumerate(grid)])[1]
    highest_expected_val_move = max([(x[2], x[0][1]) for x in possible_round_results])[1]
    hurtful_move = min([(sum(x), i) for (i, x) in enumerate(grid)])[1]
    safe_scorer_move = 0
    safe_moves = []
    for i in range(0,9,3):
        if(min([possible_round_results[i][2], possible_round_results[i+1][2], possible_round_results[i+2][2]]) >= 0):
            safe_moves.append((possible_round_results[i][2] + possible_round_results[i+1][2] + possible_round_results[i+2][2], possible_round_results[i][0][0]))
    if(len(safe_moves) > 0):
        safe_scorer_move = max(safe_moves)[1]
    else:
        #resort to naiive_score_differential after loosing out on safety
        safe_scorer_move = max([(possible_round_results[i][2] + possible_round_results[i+1][2] + possible_round_results[i+2][2], possible_round_results[i][0][0]) for i in range(0, 9, 3)])[1]
    self_move = None
    if(('facing_self' in store) and (store['facing_self'])):
        #find the two possibilities that might have been used, compare to move, and set to move if it matches to maintain self-facing status
        max_score_result_index = max([(x[1][0] + x[1][1], i) for (i, x) in enumerate(possible_round_results)])[1]
        possible_moves = possible_round_results[max_score_result_index][0]
        if(moves[1] == possible_moves[0] or moves[1] == possible_moves[1]):
            self_move = moves[1]
            if(moves[0] < moves[1] and store['should_pick_low'] is None):
                store['should_pick_low'] = True
            elif(moves[0] > moves[1] and store['should_pick_low'] is None):
                store['should_pick_low'] = False
        else:
            self_move = -1
    else:
        self_move = strategize(grid, store)

    # Populate default values for store
    if(not 'num_turns' in store):
        store['num_turns'] = 0
        store['my_score'] = 0
        store['opponent_score'] = 0
        store['opponent_strategy_probabilities'] = {
            'self': 0,
            'naiive': 0, # pick the row with the highest sum
            'naiive_score_differential': 0, # pick the row with the highest average point gain over opponent
            'hurtful': 0, # try to give opponent the column with lowest sum
            'cooperative': 0, # try to behave cooperatively
            'minimize_losses': 0, # pick row with highest minimum
            'highest_expected_val': 0, # pick row with highest sum of score differences
            'safe_scorer': 0 # determine rows with safety, then pick row with highest score differential
        }
        store['facing_self'] = False
        store['should_pick_low'] = None
    store['num_turns'] += 1
    store['my_score'] += grid[moves[0]][moves[1]]
    store['opponent_score'] += grid[moves[1]][moves[0]]

    # Used to tune adaptation of bot
    most_recent_weighting = 5

    if(moves[1] == naiive_move):
        store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['naiive'] = (most_recent_weighting + (store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['naiive'] * (store['num_turns'] - 1))) / (most_recent_weighting + store['num_turns'] - 1)
    else:
        store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['naiive'] = ((store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['naiive'] * (store['num_turns'] - 1))) / (most_recent_weighting + store['num_turns'] - 1)
    if(moves[1] == naiive_score_differnetial_move):
        store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['naiive_score_differential'] = (most_recent_weighting + (store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['naiive_score_differential'] * (store['num_turns'] - 1))) / (most_recent_weighting + store['num_turns'] - 1)
    else:
        store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['naiive_score_differential'] = ((store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['naiive_score_differential'] * (store['num_turns'] - 1))) / (most_recent_weighting + store['num_turns'] - 1)
    if(moves[1] == cooperative_move):
        store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['cooperative'] = (most_recent_weighting + (store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['cooperative'] * (store['num_turns'] - 1))) / (most_recent_weighting + store['num_turns'] - 1)
    else:
        store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['cooperative'] = ((store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['cooperative'] * (store['num_turns'] - 1))) / (most_recent_weighting + store['num_turns'] - 1)
    if(moves[1] == minimize_losses_move):
        store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['minimize_losses'] = (most_recent_weighting + (store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['minimize_losses'] * (store['num_turns'] - 1))) / (most_recent_weighting + store['num_turns'] - 1)
    else:
        store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['minimize_losses'] = ((store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['minimize_losses'] * (store['num_turns'] - 1))) / (most_recent_weighting + store['num_turns'] - 1)
    if(moves[1] == highest_expected_val_move):
        store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['highest_expected_val'] = (most_recent_weighting + (store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['highest_expected_val'] * (store['num_turns'] - 1))) / (most_recent_weighting + store['num_turns'] - 1)
    else:
        store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['highest_expected_val'] = ((store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['highest_expected_val'] * (store['num_turns'] - 1))) / (most_recent_weighting + store['num_turns'] - 1)
    if(moves[1] == hurtful_move):
        store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['hurtful'] = (most_recent_weighting + (store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['hurtful'] * (store['num_turns'] - 1))) / (most_recent_weighting + store['num_turns'] - 1)
    else:
        store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['hurtful'] = ((store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['hurtful'] * (store['num_turns'] - 1))) / (most_recent_weighting + store['num_turns'] - 1)
    if(moves[1] == safe_scorer_move):
        store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['safe_scorer'] = (most_recent_weighting + (store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['safe_scorer'] * (store['num_turns'] - 1))) / (most_recent_weighting + store['num_turns'] - 1)
    else:
        store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['safe_scorer'] = ((store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['safe_scorer'] * (store['num_turns'] - 1))) / (most_recent_weighting + store['num_turns'] - 1)
    if(moves[1] == self_move):
        store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['self'] = (most_recent_weighting + (store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['self'] * (store['num_turns'] - 1))) / (most_recent_weighting + store['num_turns'] - 1)
    else:
        store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['self'] = ((store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['self'] * (store['num_turns'] - 1))) / (most_recent_weighting + store['num_turns'] - 1)
    if(store['opponent_strategy_probabilities']['self'] == 1 and store['num_turns'] > 4):
        store['facing_self'] = True
    else:
        store['facing_self'] = False
```

Comment: There's an extra three backticks at the end; not sure why.